# Is this true: Two sets are separated iff they are disjoint and open?

Tags: general-topology

Two sets A,B are separated if no point of A lies in the closure of B and no point of B lies in the closure of A.

I know that if A and B are disjoint and open then they are separated, but is it also true that if A and B are separated then they are open and disjoint?
Thanks

Comment: Take $\{0\}$ and $\{1\}$ in $\Bbb R$.

Comment: Separated sets are necessarily disjoint, but they need not be open.

Comment: In general not necessarily open, but they are open if you look at $A$ and $B$ as subsets of $A\cup B$ equipped with subspace topology.

Answer (score 3):

If they are separated, then they are disjoint - this is quite trivial, because $$A\cap B\subset\bar A\cap   B  $$ and $$A\cap B\subset A\cap  \bar B.  $$

If they are separated, then they are not necessarily open or closed: take $A = [0,1)$ and $B= [2,3)$.

Answer (score 1):

They need not be open. But of course they are disjoint. To see why they need not be open, consider the real line, for instance, with the usual topology, and two sets $[0,1)$ and $(1,2]$. Obviously they are separated but not open.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: I misread the question

This claim is true though!
The converse is not true though: consider $[0,1]$ and $[2,3]$. They are separated (and disjoint, this is always true) but neither is open.

Comment: But I proved that if they're disjoint and open they must be separated..

Comment: The set A is open and A∩B =∅, so X\A is a closed set containing V. The closure B closure is the smallest closed set containing B, so X \A ⊃ B closure. It follows that A ∩B closure = ∅. Similarly, Aclosure ∩ B = ∅.

Comment: what's wrong with that?

Comment: Ah, no you are correct, for some reason, I read what you wrote as saying that $\bar{A} \cap \bar{B} = \emptyset$, my apologies.

Comment: oh ok no problem thanks